# Passing a pointer for a dynamic runtime function

Tags: c++, function, pointers, lambda

I'm trying to write a generic utility function for a class that applies a function to each element of a vector with the only input argument being the value of that element. The idea being that I can use that to support scalar addition/multiplication as well as user-specified functions without duplicating too much code. It works fine for the user-specified functions, but I'm struggling with how the best implement it for scalar addition/multiplication.

The code below is a simplified version of what I'm playing around with. It works fine, but what I want to be able to do is have the "5" in the lambda expression be a variable passed in separately, but not necessarily passed into "apply_f". So keep apply_f only taking a vector an a function pointer. I'm aware of the captures field for lambda expressions, but I was having trouble passing a lambda function with a capture into another function. I'm also aware of something like std::bind, but couldn't get that to work either.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

void apply_f(vector<double>& vec, double (*f)(double)) {
    transform(vec.begin(), vec.end(), vec.begin(), f);
}

int main() {
    vector<double> x {1, 2, 3};

    auto f = [](double x){ return x + 5; };
    apply_f(x, f);

    cout << x[0] << endl;
    cout << x[1] << endl;
    cout << x[2] << endl;
}
```

Comment: "I was having trouble" and "couldn't get that to work" do not help people provide solutions. What else did you try, and what did not work, specifically?

Comment: From what I understand, I can't pass lambda functions with captures as a pointer into another function.
error: cannot convert ‘main()::<lambda(double)>’ to ‘double (*)(double)’ for argument ‘2’ to ‘void apply_f(std::vector<double>&, double (*)(double))’

Comment: Does it need to be *that* generic? Could you instead simply pass in a templated callable type, as the stdlib algorithms do?

Comment: @underscore_d Yeah using a template does seem better than what I was trying to do, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Simply take a parameter with a unique type:

```
template <class F>
void apply_f(vector<double>& vec, F f) {
    transform(vec.begin(), vec.end(), vec.begin(), f);
}
```

Not only it will work, but you will get way better performance since the compiler knows the actual type being passed.

Comment: I tend to pass functors by `const&`, but I'm guessing you copy because you expect all functors to be small enough that passing by reference would offer no benefit or a slight overhead due to indirection - though inlining can make them identical anyway, probably in many cases. The only other thing I'd add is that in situations where the functor needs to hold mutable state, and it will be passed to stdlib algorithms, they'll want to pass it via `std::ref()` to get a `reference_wrapper`, to ensure updates to state between calls actually stick since various stdlib algorithms take functors by copy.

Comment: @underscore_d `std::transform` takes it by value, so in this case the best option is to do the same. As for mutable state functors, that is getting into dangerous territory: in many cases they are not that useful with the standard algorithms (e.g. `std::transform` does not guarantee the order of the calls). Even more so nowadays with the parallel algorithms!

Comment: True, `transform()` is not the right thing to use if the functor has side effects whose order of application matters (which I would assume is most cases), so `for_each()` (or range-`for`, etc.) has to be used in those cases.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, lambdas are not just pointers to functions (because they can have state, for instance). You can change your code to use a `std::function<double(double)` instead of a `double(*)(double)`, and this can capture a lambda (you may need to pass `std::cref(f)` instead of just `f`).

Comment: I don't see why `[c]ref()` would be needed. It's also not clear whether the OP really needs the heavy-handed type-erasure of `std::function` or could perhaps simply just pass in a templated callable type like stdlib algorithms.

Comment: That's why I said "may", it will depend on the actual code. But yes, perhaps using `template<typename T>void apply_f(vector<double>& vec, T f)` may be enough.